# Do we really need both [game] and [gaming] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

Currently there is a [gaming](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) tag, created 5 years ago, with 88 questions and the following usage guidance:

> Retro games, both hardware and software-based. NOT EVERY GAMING QUESTION IS ON-TOPIC. See tag wiki for guidance.

There is also a [game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag, created less than a year ago, with 19 questions and no usage guidance.

Two questions have both tags.

Is there a good reason for keeping these two tags separate, rather than merging them?  If they are to be kept separate, what is the difference between the two tags?

Comment: I mentioned this one at [my meta question about duplicate tags](/q/993), so…

Comment: Perhaps the more pressing pairings from that question should be discussed separately.  Although that list is useful as it stands.

Answer (score 5):

Good catch.  I can see no compelling reason to keep them separate.

If others agree, they can be merged.

Comment: How is that going to be determined?

Comment: @user3840170 I’ve [suggested the synonym](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/gaming/synonyms), users with enough reputation can vote it up or down.

Comment: ... and this has now been completed, the tags are synonyms.